# Can't Rotate Camera And Head Unity 3D After Build Project

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, virtual-reality

In Unity, I can play this project properly,
ALT + mouse = look left, right, up and down,
CTRL = tilt head and walking.
But when I Build this project to APK or PC (Windows), 
the head can't rotate to left or right

**this is my source code for Auto Walk,**

public class VRAutoWalk

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    // player is allowed to move
    // using Google VR button or Touchpad in Gear VR
    if (Input.GetButtonDown("Fire1")) {
        moveForward = !moveForward;
        if (moveForward == false) {
            myCC.SimpleMove(Vector3.zero);
        }
    }

    // if ALT button is pressed, rotate head
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightAlt) || Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftAlt))
    {

        // Get mouse X input
        mouseX += Input.GetAxis("Mouse X") * 5;
        // Keep mouseX value between 0 and 360
        if (mouseX <= -180) { mouseX += 360; }
        else if (mouseX > 180) { mouseX -= 360; }
        // Get mouse Y input
        mouseY += Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y") * 2.4f;
        // Keep mouseY value between 0 and 360
        if (mouseY <= -180) { mouseY += 360; }
        else if (mouseY > 180) { mouseY -= 360; }
    }

    // Check to see if I should move
    if (moveForward) {
        // Find the forward direction
        Vector3 forward = vrCamera.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
        // tell myCC to move forward
        myCC.SimpleMove(forward * speed);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to check the virtual reality supported tick in the player settings before you build